# Don't allow double space in textarea with React javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, textarea

I don't want to update the input value of the textarea if the user is trying to make a second space.

For now I'm using onChange to update the state of the text

```
onChange = {(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
```

I have tried to check for the keyCode and not update if the space is used, but the problem is that I do want one space, the second space is the one that should make the input value not update. How can I achieve that ?

Edit: I wan't to allow people to use as many spaces as they want, as long as it's not one after the other (no double space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will just want to create a function (this can be an inline anonymous function, or an extended one for readability) that filters out every time there's multiple spaces and set the text to the return of that function.

```js
onChange = {(e) => setText(e.target.value.split('').filter((val1, index, arr) => ind == 0 || val1 !== ' ' || arr[ind-1] !== ' ').join('')}
```

```js
const oneSpace = (val1, ind, arr) => {
  if (ind == 0) return true;
  if (val1 !== ' ') return true;
  const val2 = arr[ind-1];
  if (val2 !== ' ') return true;
  return false;
}

const str1 = "This is a string";

console.log(str1.split('').filter(oneSpace).join(''));

const str2 = "This  is  a  string  with  double  spaces";

console.log(str2.split('').filter(oneSpace).join(''));

const str3 = "This   is   a   string   with   triple   spaces";

console.log(str3.split('').filter(oneSpace).join(''));

const str4 = "This is      a           string        with                random       spaces";

console.log(str4.split('').filter(oneSpace).join(''));
```

Comment: I think that will not even allow one space

Comment: I think I explained it wrong, your code does work but the idea was to not allow one space after another, so not allow double space but allow (" "). My bad, will update the question

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I'm in the process of editing my answer right now